# How to compare each row of n columns in exel and print the highest value in the (n+1)th column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-office-2010

See I have two columns in Excel each contain one of the roots of a quadratic polynomial and I want to compare the roots and print the maximum in a 3rd column. (In a later work, I'll have three columns each contain one of the roots of a cubic polynomial and I'll have to compare those 3 columns, row by row and print the highest value of each row in a 4th column)

[image]

How can I do so?
(If I need to use VBA, please learn me how and where to insert the code)
I'm working with Microsoft Office 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Max in the third column or even if you have n columns use this formula:

```
=MAX(A2:B2)
```

and copy it down your Maximum Root Column it will give the Maximum Root for each Row.

```
=Max(A2:Z2)
```

also will give the Maximum Root for the columns A to Z

[image]